# A simple case of a strong version of the Berge-Fulkerson conjecture

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings, matching-theory, perfect-matchings

**UPDATE    28 June 2019** A counterexample for Conjecture 2 has been provided.  The conjecture is now demoted again to guess.  The text has been updated to reflect this change, and there is now a new question (*).

**UPDATE 12 june 2019** What was previously a “guess” was upgraded to a conjecture (Conjecture 2).  There a rationale for it, and there is also substantial computer evidence - all relevant graphs with up to 34 vertices were checked.  It will take some time to check all the graphs with 36 vertices and some that are available with 38.  We have also added some information regarding the implications of this conjecture.  The post will be updated when all graphs with 36 vertices have been checked (in about a month), or if there is progress in the actual question in the post.

> **Definition 1** Let $G$ be a bridgeless cubic graph.  Define a Fulkerson cover of $G$ to be a collection of six perfect matchings in $G$, not necessarily distinct, which together cover each edge of $G$ twice.  We say that $G$ *admits* a Fulkerson cover if there is a Fulkerson cover for $G$.

Fulkerson, and also Berge, proposed the following notorious conjecture.

> **Conjecture 1** [Fulkerson, 1971, and Berge]. Every bridgeless cubic graph admits a Fulkerson cover.

A natural question that comes to mind is whether for any bridgeless cubic graph $G$ and any perfect matching $M$ of $G$ there is a Fulkerson cover of $G$ which includes $M$.

> **Definition 2** We call a pair $(G,M)$ a *configuration* and if $G$ admits a Fulkerson cover that includes $M$ we say that $(G,M)$ *extends* to a Fulkerson cover.

It is possible to see that in general configurations don’t extend to Fulkerson covers. See figure for an example of a graph and a perfect matching which does not extend to a Fulkerson cover:

[image: (G,M) does not extend to a Fulkerson cover]

However, we guessed that if $G$ is cyclically edge-5-connected, then this is true. All relevant graphs with up to 34 vertices were checked without finding a counterexample, and many more with 36 vertices.  The guess was an educated guess, based on the role that the Petersen graph plays in preventing the extension of configurations to Fulkerson covers. Cyclical edge-5-connectedness precludes the existence of pieces of the Petersen graph as subgraphs of the graphs involved in the configuration.

> **Guess** If $G$ is cyclically edge-5-connected cubic graph and $M$ is any perfect matching of $G$ then $G$ admits a Fulkerson cover which includes $M$.
>
> Mazzuoccolo has provided a counterexample of this guess, that was shown to him by T. Kaiser in 2011.
>
> **Counterexample** [T. Kaiser, per G. Mazzuoccolo] Let $G$ be a 5-regular graph that is not edge 5 colorable, and which is cyclically edge 5 connected.  Blow every vertex up to a pentagon to get a new cubic graph $G’$ and pick $M$ to be the edges that are not on the new pentagons.  Then $M$ does not extend to a Fulkerson cover of $G’$, because if it would, $G$ would be edge 5 colorable,
>
> **Question** (*) If $G$ is a cyclically edge 6 connected cubic graph and $M$ is any perfect matching in $G$, does $G$ admit a Fulkerson cover which includes $M$?

For a definition of cyclical edge connectedness see the reference below [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRmlI.png). This looks very hard to prove, in fact, it would almost imply Berge and Fulkerson’s conjecture (following a very recent result which shows that the smallest counterexample to Conjecture 1 must be a cyclically edge-5-connected graph - Má˘cajová and Mazzuoccolo [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwXiD.png)).

But getting to the point of our question, it pertains to a special case of Question (*), where the cyclical connectedness restriction is lifted:

> **Definition 3** Let a *prism* be a cubic graph $G$ consisting of two disjoint circuits of the same length connected by a perfect matching $M$.  We say that the configuration $(G,M)$ is *prismatic*.

Our question then is:

> **MAIN QUESTION 1** Let $(G,M)$ be a prismatic configuration.  Does it extend to a Fulkerson cover? If the answer is yes, how do you prove it?  If it is no, can you show a counterexample?

We believe this is true and the computer based data supports it.  We are hoping that this is not too difficult and one of our readers can verify it.  One can think of this problem as an edge coloring problem.  To see this, double all the edges not in $M$.  Then the resulting graph is a 5-regular multigraph.  The question then becomes whether the chromatic index of this multigraph is 5.

> **EDIT Question 2** I believe the question has a positive answer if and only if it is possible to find a partition of the edges in $M$ into five parts $A_i, 1\le i\le 5$, such that  $G-M-V(A_i)$ is of even order.  Can you prove this equivalence or show a counterexample?  This shouldn’t be too hard.

One can see that the cardinality of $A_i$ is of the same parity as the cardinality of $M$.

An example of such a partition, which evidently extends to a Fulkerson cover which includes five other matchings, one of each color ...

[image: prismatic configuration 13a]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRmlI.png) Nedela, R. and Skoviera, M. Atoms of cyclic connectivity in cubic graphs, Mathematica Slovaca 45 5 (1995) 481-499.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwXiD.png) Má˘cajová, E. and Mazzuoccolo, G., Smallest counterexample to the Fulkerson conjecture must be cyclically 5-edge-connected, 54-th Czech-Slovak Conference Graphs 2019, (2019)

Comment: Thanks to T. Jensen for helping formulate question 2.

Comment: Thanks to B. McKay for pointing out the lists of snarks for testing the “guess” - this will take a while, but we will report back.

Comment: Thanks to G. Mazzuoccolo for providing the counterexample to Conjecture 2, now Guess.